# Changing gradient colour positions for sunrise background in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have a question on gradients with Android Studio. I want to make a sunrise background for my app and I am able to make a basic gradient like the one below using the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient android:startColor="@color/sunriseblue"
    android:centerColor="@color/sunrisePink"
    android:endColor="@color/sunriseYellow"></gradient>

</shape>
```

This creates a background gradient where each colour equally occupies a third of the gradient.

I am now wondering how I can modify the positions of the individual colours in the gradient such that I can make the background like this:

[desired background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ6EM.png)

So the majority of the screen is yellow and there is very little blue at the top. Thanks!

Comment: I copy your code and pasted in android studio but no problem. can you share project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the center color to be more similar to the predominant one. In addition, use the **centerY** to control the center color position:

```
    <gradient
            android:centerY="25%"
            android:startColor="#FF315963"
            android:centerColor="#FFEAA55C"
            android:endColor="#FFEAD05C"/>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:centerX` to change the center position of your middle color